# TypeError: 'int' object is not callable whats is wrong?

Tags: python, object, int, typeerror, callable

Hi I`m currently working on a small project for school and the task is to write a function which takes a dna strand and a position and checks whether the DNA is complement before and after the picked position.
this is the code i came up with so far. 
the translate function is just to check complementarity and it workes just fine.
but if i try to feed a DNA to the lis function, i get an error.

```
File "xxx", line 37, in lis
while translate(dna[pos(1-i)],dna[pos(1+i)])=="TRUE":

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

does anybody know what is going wrong there?

```
def translate(seq, comp):
#matchlist and checklist
    basecomplement = {'A': 'T', 'C': 'G', 'G': 'C', 'T': 'A'}
    baselist = ["A","T","G","C"]
#check wether the input is a DNA
    if seq not in baselist:
        print("FALSE")
    elif comp not in baselist:
        print("FALSE")
#check if the two (or more) bases are complements    
    else:    
        aaseq = []
        comp = [comp]
        for character in seq:
            aaseq.append(basecomplement[character])
            print(aaseq)
#print result            
            if aaseq == comp:
                print("TRUE")
            else:
                print("FALSE")

def lis(dna, pos):
#make a list from DNA input    
    dna = [dna]
#go to pos in DNA list    
    for pos in range(len(dna)):
        i=1
#check if position before and after pos are complements
#and advance a position if true else stop
        while translate(dna[pos(1-i)],dna[pos(1+i)])=="TRUE":
                i+=1
                return(pos-i + pos+i)
        break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things for you to fix in here...

- `pos` is an integer, not a function so `pos(1-i)` is causing the error in your post. This should be something like `dna[pos-1]` and `dna[pos+1]`
- `range` starts at 0 so `0-1` is going to be `-1` and will throw an out of range error as well
- `translate()` isn't returning anything, only printing. You need `return ("TRUE")`. You'd also be better off using boolean `True` and `False` here instead of strings.

I didn't go through your entire snippet, so there may be more quirks...